# Need a report on data center costs

Tags: datacenter, permissions

I'm looking for some information on the costs of running a data center, preferably a company report not just on inital costs but also monthly and/or annual operational costs. Is there any such report that you know of disclosed by some company? If so, I'd appreciate some links.

P.S. I'm looking for exact numbers that a company published, but estimates are also of interest.

Comment: Such information would likely be useless without quite a few details (generally kept private) about what they're doing with said datacenter.

Comment: Shopping, too localized (that is, too specific to your situation).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any company that would be interested in making this internal financial information public. Figure out the costs for your specific situation.